# how to change query so it only shows name instead whole array (laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I got a query that gets the data into a collection, problem is that it shows foreign id but i want it to display what i have given in the url parameters.

- `columnsGiven` is the parameter from url. contains column names with child: "language.name". so `column=active,title,language.name`

For example i get this:

```
"name": "george",
"active": 1,
"language": 1,
```

and this is what i want:

```
"name": "george",
"active": 1,
"language": "Dutch",
```

this is my code:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $columnsGiven = explode(',', $request->columns);
    $tableName = $request->table_name; //example: 'support_guide_translations'
    $modelName = $request->model_name; //example: "App\Models\SupportGuideTranslation";


    if($request->search){
        $query = $modelName::search($request->search);
    } else{
        $query = $modelName::query();
        if($request->sort){
            $sort = explode('?', $request->sort);
            $query->orderBy($sort[0], $sort[1]);
        }
    }
    foreach ($request->query() as $key => $value) {
        // dd($value);
        if(!$value == ""){
            if(Schema::hasColumn($tableName, $key)){
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
            if(in_array($key, $columnsGiven)){
                dd('true');
            }
            //     $searchWord = Str::contains('account123',$request->search);
        }
    }

    $guides = $query->get();
    return GuideResource::collection($guides);
}
}
```

this is GuideResource, it sends data to vue by making it json first. Not allowed to make changes here, it has to be done in the function index. :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'body' => $this->body,
        'active' => $this->active,
        'language' => $this->language,
        'support_guide' => $this->support_guide,
        'support_guide_group' => $this->support_guide_group,

    ];
}
```

Comment: can you show GuideResource

Comment: @JohnLobo i updated everything. :)

Comment: 'language' => $this->language->name,  have you tried this

Comment: The purpose is to make it dynamically so i dont want to change GuideResource. It has to be all done in function index.

Answer (score 0):

```
"language": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dutch",
    "code": "NL",
    "created_at": "2021-06-14T10:10:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-14T10:10:32.000000Z"
},
```

I believe `"language"` has a relationship with another model.

Isn't this what you are looking for?

```
return [
    // your other attributes...

    'language' => $this->language->relationshipName->name,
];
```

where `relationshipName` is the method name in the `Language` model.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post that GuideResource is not allowed to be change. Purpose is to make this  dynamically, i fill in which columns i want in url and the function index should do the rest.

Comment: @SaiyanPrice i updated the whole post. it now makes sense what i wrote sorry.